# Remote control application

Tags: python, remote, java, communication

I connected raspberry with my pc over wireless network. I can use ssh communication, and server installed on my raspberry with my pc's web browser.

I need another solution to control my rpi (not rpi's server communication that is not fast enough for my project)

I mean that I want to program 2 applications on my pc and raspberry that run and communicate with each other.

I couldn't find solution. Python and java is preferable. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tcp server application written in python on your raspberry pi and a tcp client application on your pc/phone. Plenty examples can be found on the net.

Comment: Thanks brother. That is what i looking for. I hope it will be as fast as I want.